C# Selenium ChromeDriver, how to perform window zoom out function?
What I need to accomplish is the same exact functionality as the cntrl+ or contrl- key strokes in the chrome driver.  Using the javascript way does not bring all the elements into view.
I've tried the below code, plus every form of Javascript I can find and I cannot get the zoom in/out browser functionality to occur.  Any help is appreciated.
public void Zoom()
    {
        //browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys(protractor.Key.SUBTRACT).keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
        /*
        OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions action = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(_library._driver);
        action.SendKeys(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Subtract).SendKeys(Keys.Null);
        Actions builder = new Actions(_library._driver).KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Subtract).SendKeys(Keys.Subtract).KeyUp(Keys.Control).Perform();
        builder.Perform();*/
        Actions action = new Actions(_library._driver);
        action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Subtract).SendKeys(Keys.Subtract).KeyUp(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Null).Perform();
    }


You can execute script to set zoom via css.. i.e.: document.body.style.zoom = "50%"

@browsermator i tried that approach, however it doesn't bring the elemenbts into view, instead it just shrinks the whole page with scroll bars
